# Why can't Googlebot crawl this robots.txt?

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt, googlebot

I don't understand why Googlebot can't crawl and index a WordPress website I created. This is what I have for my robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /content/
Allow: /content/uploads/
```

Comment: What makes you think that your site is not being crawled? It takes time for Google to detect new sites (especially if not linked to from anywhere). You can submit a crawl request via http://www.google.co.uk/submityourcontent/tools.html#web  but even that can take time before they get around to it.

Comment: It's been over a week now. I've been waiting and waiting... I guess I will do some more waiting. I thought it was a matter of a few days... guess not. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and I might add, when I search for the domain specificcaly, Google says it the content of this website can't be indexed because of the rules in robots.txt... this is why I was confused. That's all.

Comment: So, you did submit your site to Google? Can you share the URL, or would you rather not? Your robots.txt certainly looks ok - what was the exact error message from Google?

Answer (score 0):

sorry i dont have permission to comment , so maybe sounds silly but you can check in admin panel

go to settings --> reading --> and Search Engine Visibility got to be unchecked

also in your frontend press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and look for a meta

```
     <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

maybe a plugin is setting the meta robots,

Comment: I checked and the visibility is unchecked and no meta data related to 'robots'. I think I just have to be patient a little longer. Thanks though! I also did the Robot Tester from Google Development tools... but that didn't do much more than what I already knew.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google's webmaster tools and add your site there. On left, go to tab 'Crawl' -> Fetch as Google. Now you should see the error, or then button 'Submit to index'. Submit your page and it should be indexed in couple of days.